Google Oauth 2.0 throwing error "invalid_grant" in .net 6 project
{
"error": {
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Invalid grant: account not found",
"error_uri": null
},
"statusCode": 400,
"message": "Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid grant: account not found", Uri:""",
"data": {},
"innerException": null,
"helpLink": null,
"source": "Google.Apis.Auth",
"hResult": -2146233088,
"stackTrace": "   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.FromHttpResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, IClock clock, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.RequestExtensions.PostFormAsync(Object request, HttpClient httpClient, String url, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeaderValue, IClock clock, ILogger logger, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_01.<<WithCancellationToken>g__ImplAsync|0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>g__LogException|10_0(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.CredentialInterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest1.ExecuteUnparsedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest1.ExecuteAsync()\r\n   at GoogleDriveController.CheckSubscription(String subscriptionId, String token) in E:\PRImages\PRImages.API\PRImages.API\Controllers\GoogleDriveController.cs:line 50"
}Swagger Error image 
enter image description here
when I try to call an goole API to fetch the subscription detials I see this error unable to udentitfy the reason update the Json key as well.
can some please help me with this.
